# How to list languages supported by my application

Tags: android

The application has a number of localization folders:

```
values-cs
values-da
values-de
values-es
...
```

How can I enumerate all the supported languages at runtime? Sure, I can define some constant that lists all that values "cs, da, de, ..." but want to avoid doing this.

Comment: Surely the manual process of maintaining  the list of languages supported by your app doesn't compare to the effort required to arrange a decent translation into a new language. You'll probably spend more time figuring out how to automate it than you'll ever spend updating the list by hand....I've probably spent longer typing this message...

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work...

```
enum Language {
      en, fr, de, cs
}
```

And then in your activity...

```
List<Language> langs = new ArrayList<Language>();
for(String lan : ctx.getAssets().list("/res")) {
 if(lan.startsWith("values-")) {
   langs.add(Language.valueOf(lan.substring(lan.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)))'
 }
}
```

Comment: Why use an `enum` at all? Why not just save them as an array of `String`s?

Comment: I don't know. For the lulz? I gave him the basic idea.