# List of languages supported by the application

Tags: objective-c, ios7, localization

a simple and trivial question, is there any ´official´ way to retrive the list of languages supported by the mobile application in iOS? I don't mean the one supported by the OS, i mean right the one corresponding to the different en.lproj, de.lproj, ecc against which NSLocalizedString while check if the System prefered language is supported by the app.

I need the language id ("en", "de", ...) to load dinamically some content (to which i can't apply the default localization framework as in the rest) that must be coherent with the whole app lang.

Obviously apart from just reading FS like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100938/how-to-list-languages-supported-by-my-application)
or writing the language code "en" in language files.

I need it to check which

Thank you.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Please give example.

Comment: I need t pick a file as 
"a_name-en.html" 
"a_name-de.html" "a-path-fr.html" and working with it based on the language picked by NSLocal in the rest of the application. and fallback on another language if not present. I know that this does not really follow best practices, but i am not responsible and can't change it.

Comment: "I need t pick a file as "a_name-en.html" "a_name-de.html" "a-path-fr.html" But if you localize that file, that will happen automatically; you'll get the right one for the current locale, and fall back on the base.

Comment: Yes, i wish i could but i have been told not to. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file names to Localizable.strings files. In your case have a key called "fileName" and define the file names in each localisable string files. By calling `NSLocalizedString(@"fileName", nil)` you will get the correct file name according to the current device language. The OS will handle the fall back if it couldn't find the fileName in particular string file.

Comment: It´s what i wanted to avoid since i don´t want to mess the translator. Thanks anyway i upvoted !